# Best way to get a Type object from a string in .NET

Tags: .net, reflection, system.reflection

What is the best way to convert a string into a Type object in .NET?

Issues to consider:

- The type may be in a different assembly.
- The type's assembly may not be loaded yet.

This is my attempt, but it doesn't address the second issue

```
Public Function FindType(ByVal name As String) As Type
    Dim base As Type

    base = Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly.GetType(name, False, True)
    If base IsNot Nothing Then Return base

    base = Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetType(name, False, True)
    If base IsNot Nothing Then Return base

    For Each assembly As Reflection.Assembly In _
      AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies
        base = assembly.GetType(name, False, True)
        If base IsNot Nothing Then Return base
    Next
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Addressing the second case is difficult. How to know generically where the unloaded assemblies are residing? Otherwise see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7286354/661933), quite good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you might need to call GetReferencedAssemblies() method for the second.

```
namespace reflectme
{
    using System;
    public class hello
    {
        public hello()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hello");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Type t = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType("reflectme.hello");
            t.GetConstructor(System.Type.EmptyTypes).Invoke(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use [Type.GetType(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx) in order to do this.  The type name must be assembly qualified but the method will load the assembly as necessary.  The assembly qualification is not necessary if the type is in mscorlid or the assembly which executes the GetType call.

Comment: Note that this does not throw an exception if the type is not found, it returns null. If you are expecting the type to exist then it's worth using the Type.GetType(string,bool) overload and passing true, which throws if the type cannot be loaded.

Comment: "assembly qualified" means you have to put the FULL type name, like this: "NLog, Version=1.0.0.505, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c, processorArchitecture=MSIL"

Comment: That doesn't help me much, there is zero chance of me having fully qualified names.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can handle the second case as its up to the runtime to handle the loading of the assemblies. There are ways to dynamically load assemblies but that feels heavy handed.

To find the actual assembly that has the class you are looking for you can use a reference to another class that exists in the same assembly. For example, you want to load an App_Code assembly and you know another class that's in App_Code called `MyWidget`.

```
Dim assy_app_code = Assembly.GetAssembly(GetType("MyWidget"))
```

Now you can load the other class using its name:

```
Dim t as Type = assy_app_code.GetType(name)
```