# Type.GetType returns null for DataContractSerializer

Tags: c#

The parameter value I'm passing is:

"System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer, System.Runtime.Serialization"

When I add the bool parameter to throw an exception I get a FileNotFoundException.

I can't find any documentation on why this wouldn't work. The only problems I can find related to this method involve callers not specifying the assembly name.

Also, my project has an assembly reference to System.Runtime.Serialization.

```
var type = Type.GetType("System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer, System.Runtime.Serialization", true);
```

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: Have you added an assembly reference to `System.Runtime.Serialization` in your project?

Comment: Yes, the project has an assembly reference to System.Runtime.Serialization. Added that point to the question, thanks.

Comment: Very odd. Can you post the details of the `FileNotFound` exception?

Comment: You would need to add the Version, Culture and PublicKeyToken which are missing in your *QualifiedAssemblyName*. To achieve what you want without requiring those parameters, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367652/how-type-gettype-works-when-given-partially-qualified-type-name (Note that the assembly needs to be loaded already, otherwise it would not work)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the `Type` object that represents the `DataContractSerializer`, you can use the `typeof` operator:

```
Type type = typeof(System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer);
```

Comment: The string value is actually a parameter in a method. I only showed the literal value here for illustration.