# Type.GetType() returns null when a dll is dynamically loaded

Tags: c#, .net

I have quite the similar problem like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367652/how-type-gettype-works-when-given-partially-qualified-type-name).

When I load an assembly at runtime into appDomain:

```
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(assemblyName);
```

then

```
    Type.GetType("Namespace, AssemblyName");
```

returns null while fully qualified name returns the type correctly

```
    Type.GetType("Namespace, AssemblyName, Version, Culture, PublicKeyToken");
```

Se the question is why does the partially qualified name not work in this case and is there any way to force it to work?

I know I can iterate loaded assemblies and get the type that way

```
foreach (var assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
{
    assembly.GetType("Namespace");
    ...
}
```

but I'd prefer the solution above.

Comment: I suppose the call woun´t work on a statically loaded context also. Have you tried to add a reference to the assembly and get it´s types by using sort name?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/w3f99sx1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
Parameter documentation: "The assembly-qualified name of the type to get. See AssemblyQualifiedName. If the type is in the currently executing assembly or in Mscorlib.dll, it is sufficient to supply the type name qualified by its namespace."

AssemblyQualifiedName is something like "System.Array, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"

Comment: I cannot reference that assembly. I have its name in config file and its supposed to be loaded only when needed. But I accept the fact its not possible geting the type through Type.GetType() in this case. I will use the assembly.GetType() workaround then.