# Convert string to activity name C#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am using a ListView in Xamarin Android to display a list of restaurants, and when one is clicked on I would like to navigate to a new activity. The activity for each is named using this convention: [restaurantName]Activity. 
I'm trying to use intents:

```
    protected override void OnListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        string t = items[position] + "Activity";
        var intentPlace = new Intent(this, typeof(???));
        StartActivity(intentPlace);
    }
```

String t gives the correct format, but is the wrong type to put inside the typeof(). However, I have no idea what to put in place of the '???', as I wasn't able to use setTitle  in order to create the activity name. 
Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need attach full path for your Activities.

```
var actType = Type.GetType("part of full path" + items[position] + "Activity")
```

I haven't tested it, but it should work :)

```
protected override void OnListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
    var actType = Type.GetType("part of full path" + items[position] + "Activity")
    var intentPlace = new Intent(this, actType);
    StartActivity(intentPlace);
}
```

Also usefull [if the assembly with activity has been loaded in the current domain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7286354/2313116)

Comment: I just tried it out, and though it compiled when I clicked on the item I got the error: 
'[MonoDroid] System.ArgumentException: type
[MonoDroid] Parameter name: Type is not derived from a java type.'
Is this a feature that is only available in Java?

Comment: Okay, what about get fullpath for type via reflection from existing Activity and then put it in "part of full path"?

Comment: It worked, I just had to change the path name (I had an extra 'Activity' in there). Thank you!